# High first time cost for unserialize in R

Tags: r, serialization, deserialization

Unserialize in base package takes too much time when done for the first time, afterward it runs fast. 
eg.

```
>system.time(iris_model <- readRDS("./iris_model.rds"))
user  system elapsed 
3.145   0.102   3.417 
>system.time(iris_model <- readRDS("./sonar_model.rds"))
user  system elapsed 
0.029   0.003   0.032
```

here size of sonar model is 10 times iris model but reading iris takes more time.

```
>library(redux)
>r<-redux::hiredis()
>system.time(a<-r$GET('iris'))
user  system elapsed 
0.000   0.001   0.002 
>for(i in 1:10) { print(system.time(unserialize(a))) } 
user  system elapsed 
2.157   0.087   2.244 
user  system elapsed 
0.001   0.000   0.001 
user  system elapsed 
0.002   0.000   0.001 
user  system elapsed 
0.001   0.000   0.002 
user  system elapsed 
0.002   0.000   0.002 
user  system elapsed 
0.001   0.000   0.001 
user  system elapsed 
0.001   0.000   0.001 
user  system elapsed 
0.001   0.000   0.001 
user  system elapsed 
0.002   0.000   0.001 
user  system elapsed 
0.001   0.000   0.001
```

again it took time to Unserialize "a" first time then it was fast. Why is it happening that Unserialize function invoked for the first time (in a new session) takes more time? How to reduce this time?